# Improper filling of multipolygons

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I'm new in QGIS and I'm trying to do very simple thing:

1. Filter OSM data: `natural=water`
2. Add Vector Layer, select `multipolygons`

Here is what I got with QGIS:

[image]

Some islands are filled with blue (why?), but others are not (as expected).
I've checked with JOSM that all islands and the lake mapped correctly (inner/outer roles), and the only difference is that the 1st ones are "closed ways" and the 2nd ones are "relations" with `type=multipolygon`. But, as far as I understand, there is nothing wrong with it.

So, what I'm doing wrong and how can I get the proper result (all islands are not filled) with QGIS?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279909/polygon-holes-rings-are-showing-up-as-polygons-in-qgis

Comment: Similar problem https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250950/problem-importing-osm-multipolygon-buildings-with-inner-courtyards-into-qgis

Answer (score 1):

a closed way is a closed way and not an area. multipolygons are areas.

only areas will be filled.